# vuejs recursive single file components

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

> Unknown custom element:  - did you register the component
>   correctly? For recursive components, make sure to provide the "name"
>   option.

I have a Sidebar that contains a TreeList that contains TreeNodes that each contain a TreeList.

I have read plenty about other people having problems with this. I have tried solutions such as specifying kebab case names for the components. I have read about this being a problem with namespace and I agree, because I have an example working with all components in a single file. When the components are in separate files the above error occurs when reloading my script using vue CLI. Occasionally and without explanation when saving my file the error goes away and the recursion works again.

Then when it works correctly there is an error when clicking on child nodes.

> Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
>       at simpleNormalizeChildren

Is it something do with vue CLI serve?
I am open to declaring these things in the global namespace except I'm not sure how that would work exactly.

```
import TreeList from './TreeList.vue'

export default {
    name: 'tree-node',
    components: {
        'tree-list': TreeList
    },
```

...

```
import TreeNode from './TreeNode.vue'

export default {
    name: 'tree-list',
    components: {
        'tree-node': TreeNode
    }
```

...

```
import TreeList from './TreeList.vue'
import TreeNode from './TreeNode.vue'

export default {
    name: 'Sidebar',
    components: {
        TreeList,
        TreeNode
    }
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is probably happening because of the [circular referencing](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-edge-cases.html#Circular-References-Between-Components) between your `TreeList` and `TreeNode` components ..

> When you look closely, you’ll see that these components will actually
> be each other’s descendent and ancestor in the render tree - a
> paradox!

To resolve this paradox you can either register your components globally using `Vue.component`, or you can defer the import of one of your components to a later point (by moving your import to the `beforeCreate` hook or using [async components](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-dynamic-async.html#Async-Components) as demonstrated [here](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-edge-cases.html#Circular-References-Between-Components)) ..

`TreeList.vue`

```
export default {
    name: 'tree-list',
    components: {
        'tree-node': () => import('./TreeNode.vue')
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: Success. I am now using the before create hook `beforeCreate: function () {
       this.$options.components.TreeList = require('./TreeList.vue').default
     },`

Comment: I couldn't make a crazy recursive tree even declaring the component globally, but this did the trick!

Answer (score 1):

With Vue 3, you can use Async Components:

```js
export default {
  name: 'tree-list',
  components: {
    'tree-node': defineAsyncComponent(() => import('./TreeNode.vue'))
  }
}
```

Documentation:

- https://v3-migration.vuejs.org/breaking-changes/async-components.html#_3-x-syntax
- https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/component-dynamic-async.html#async-components

Comment: In fact you can use it for Vue 2.7 too, but if you are trying to make Vite 2 work with Vite it will not help, it is just a dummy method to help migrate to Vue 3 Synthax.

Answer (score -1):

You can pass imported components around as data. You can even pass them in as a prop or in an object passed in to a prop.

```js
<!-- TheParent.vue -->
<template>
  <RecursiveComponent
    :nodes="nodes"
    :component="RecursiveComponent"
  />
</template>
<script>
import RecursiveComponent from '@/components/RecursiveComponent.vue';

export default {
  name: 'TheParent',
  components: {
    RecursiveComponent
  },
  data: function () {
    return {
      nodes: {
        a: {
          b: {
            c: 22
          }
        },
        d: 33
      }
    };
  },
  computed: {
    RecursiveComponent: function () {
      return RecursiveComponent;
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

```js
<!-- RecursiveComponent.vue -->
<template>
  <ul>
    <li v-for="(value, key) in nodes">
      <strong>{{ key }}: </strong>
      <template v-if="typeof(value) !== 'object'">
        {{ nodes[key] }}
      </template>
      <component
        v-else
        :is="component"
        :nodes="value"
        :component="component"
      />
    </li>
  </ul>
</template>
<script>
export default {
  name: 'RecursiveComponent',
  props: {
    nodes: {
      type: Object,
      required: true
    },
    component: {
      type: Object,
      required: true
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

**Note:**

- This works fine locally, and when you build your project for production, but some online editors (like CodeSandbox) will struggle with live-updating recursive code.
- The component is stored in the `computed` section, to be accessible by the template. You could store it in `data`, but Vue warns that it will become reactive (which isn't great). You could also put it in the `constants` section if using [this plugin](https://github.com/TheJaredWilcurt/vue-options-api-constants-plugin).

```js
import RecursiveComponent from '@/components/RecursiveComponent.vue';

export default {
  name: 'TheParent',
  components: {
    RecursiveComponent
  },
  constants: {
    RecursiveComponent
  },
  data: function () {
    return {
      nodes: {
        a: {
          b: {
            c: 22
          }
        },
        d: 33
      }
    };
  }
};
```